# Mongodb: $round decimal

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to round the average salary to 2 decimal places. I'm stumped, I can get either everyones salary to 2 decimal places

```
db.employees.aggregate([{$project: {_id: null, 'roundedSal':{$round: [{$avg: '$salary'}]}}}])
```

which returns

> { "_id" : null, "roundedSal" : 48501.24 } { "_id" : null, "roundedSal"
> : 45999.71 } { "_id" : null, "roundedSal" : 35554.54 } { "_id" : null,
> "roundedSal" : 47700 } { "_id" : null, "roundedSal" : 48123.25 } {
> "_id" : null, "roundedSal" : 44415.94 } { "_id" : null, "roundedSal" :
> 42925.26 } { "_id" : null, "roundedSal" : 31500.66 } { "_id" : null, "roundedSal" : 50500.25 }

or get the overall average

```
db.employees.aggregate([{$group: {_id: null, 'roundedSal':{$avg: '$salary'}}}])

{ "_id" : null, "roundedSal" : 43913.427777777775 }
```

but I can't manage to figure out how to round this to two decimal places without an error being thrown

Comment: Use the second argument.

Answer (score 1):

Please read the [mongo documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/round/) it's one of the bestest documentantions in my opinion.

```
// { $round : [ <number>, <place> ] }

db.employees.aggregate([{$project: {_id: null, 'roundedSal':{$round: [{$avg: '$salary'}, 2]}}}])
```